# Route not working(showing blank page) in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I'm new to Laravel. I'm getting this issue from a long while. I've added a route to a page in web.php but it is showing a blank page instead of going to that page.

**Here are the routes in web.php:**

```
    Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','admin']], function() {
//For Admin Dashboard
  Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
      return view('admin.dashboard');
  });
//For listing users
  Route::get('/users-list', function () {
      return view('admin.users');
  });
});
```

The users-list route is not working. The **users.blade.php** file is placed in **admin** folder.
I'm trying to add the path directory to url but still not working. Here is another thing I'm trying.

**Navbar**

```
     <li>
    <!-- <a href="{{ url('/admin/users') }}">  -->
<a href="{{ url('/users-list') }}">
      <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
      <p>Users Profiles</p>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Here is my views directory
[image: Views]

I'm trying to access it from here but still no results, same blank page. There's something wrong which I'm not able to find out. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.
I'll be happy to provide any sorts of other details if required.

Comment: are you logged in before accessing the pages?

Comment: Yes, I'm logged in

Comment: If he is not logged in, how he can view the blank page?

Comment: Can you also provide the screen capture of your view

Comment: @Poldo screen capture of what view?

Comment: @Poldo I've added it

Comment: whats the url of the blank page in browser??

Comment: @zahidhasanemon 
Here you go:
http://localhost/testWeb/public/users-list

Comment: @MurtazaAhmad Your `admin` middleware logic for admin users only right?

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya yes

Comment: If any other details are required, I'll be happy to provide them

Comment: Please check your `users.blade.php` file or share with us. Because you see only blank page without error and your route file is correct.

Comment: Alright, I'm updating my question and adding users.blade.php file   @YusufUlusoy

Comment: @YusufUlusoy that file is correct, it has nothing important. If you still want to see I can add it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright everyone, thanks alot for your answers and suggestions. I think I have found my issue.

I was using a layout file for **dashboard.blade.php** and **users-list.blade.php** named **master.blade.php**. And issue was in that file as it was not displaying output. I've corrected it and it worked.
Here is my **users.blade.php**

```
    @extends('layouts.master')
    @section('title')
    Users Profiles | TestWeb
    @endsection


    @section('content')

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-title"> Simple Table</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead class=" text-primary">
                  <th>
                    Name
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Country
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    City
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-right">
                    Salary
                  </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Dakota Rice
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Niger
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Oud-Turnhout
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $36,738
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Minerva Hooper
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Curaçao
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Sinaai-Waas
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $23,789
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Sage Rodriguez
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Netherlands
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Baileux
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $56,142
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Philip Chaney
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Korea, South
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Overland Park
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $38,735
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Doris Greene
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Malawi
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Feldkirchen in Kärnten
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $63,542
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Mason Porter
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Chile
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Gloucester
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $78,615
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Jon Porter
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Portugal
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Gloucester
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $98,615
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card card-plain">
          <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="card-title"> Table on Plain Background</h4>
            <p class="category"> Here is a subtitle for this table</p>
          </div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table">
                <thead class=" text-primary">
                  <th>
                    Name
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    Country
                  </th>
                  <th>
                    City
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-right">
                    Salary
                  </th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Dakota Rice
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Niger
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Oud-Turnhout
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $36,738
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Minerva Hooper
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Curaçao
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Sinaai-Waas
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $23,789
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Sage Rodriguez
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Netherlands
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Baileux
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $56,142
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Philip Chaney
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Korea, South
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Overland Park
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $38,735
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Doris Greene
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Malawi
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Feldkirchen in Kärnten
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $63,542
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Mason Porter
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Chile
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Gloucester
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $78,615
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                      Jon Porter
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Portugal
                    </td>
                    <td>
                      Gloucester
                    </td>
                    <td class="text-right">
                      $98,615
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    @endsection

And @extends('layouts.master')
@section('title')
Users Profiles | TestWeb
@endsection


@section('content')

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title"> Simple Table</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <thead class=" text-primary">
              <th>
                Name
              </th>
              <th>
                Country
              </th>
              <th>
                City
              </th>
              <th class="text-right">
                Salary
              </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Dakota Rice
                </td>
                <td>
                  Niger
                </td>
                <td>
                  Oud-Turnhout
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $36,738
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Minerva Hooper
                </td>
                <td>
                  Curaçao
                </td>
                <td>
                  Sinaai-Waas
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $23,789
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Sage Rodriguez
                </td>
                <td>
                  Netherlands
                </td>
                <td>
                  Baileux
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $56,142
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Philip Chaney
                </td>
                <td>
                  Korea, South
                </td>
                <td>
                  Overland Park
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $38,735
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Doris Greene
                </td>
                <td>
                  Malawi
                </td>
                <td>
                  Feldkirchen in Kärnten
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $63,542
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Mason Porter
                </td>
                <td>
                  Chile
                </td>
                <td>
                  Gloucester
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $78,615
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Jon Porter
                </td>
                <td>
                  Portugal
                </td>
                <td>
                  Gloucester
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $98,615
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="card card-plain">
      <div class="card-header">
        <h4 class="card-title"> Table on Plain Background</h4>
        <p class="category"> Here is a subtitle for this table</p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table">
            <thead class=" text-primary">
              <th>
                Name
              </th>
              <th>
                Country
              </th>
              <th>
                City
              </th>
              <th class="text-right">
                Salary
              </th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Dakota Rice
                </td>
                <td>
                  Niger
                </td>
                <td>
                  Oud-Turnhout
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $36,738
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Minerva Hooper
                </td>
                <td>
                  Curaçao
                </td>
                <td>
                  Sinaai-Waas
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $23,789
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Sage Rodriguez
                </td>
                <td>
                  Netherlands
                </td>
                <td>
                  Baileux
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $56,142
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Philip Chaney
                </td>
                <td>
                  Korea, South
                </td>
                <td>
                  Overland Park
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $38,735
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Doris Greene
                </td>
                <td>
                  Malawi
                </td>
                <td>
                  Feldkirchen in Kärnten
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $63,542
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Mason Porter
                </td>
                <td>
                  Chile
                </td>
                <td>
                  Gloucester
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $78,615
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Jon Porter
                </td>
                <td>
                  Portugal
                </td>
                <td>
                  Gloucester
                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                  $98,615
                </td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And **master.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/assets/img/apple-icon.png">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/img/favicon.png">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
  <title>
    @yield('title')
  </title>
  <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, shrink-to-fit=no' name='viewport' />
  <!--     Fonts and icons     -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700,200" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <!-- CSS Files -->
  <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="{{ asset('assets/css/now-ui-dashboard.css?v=1.3.0') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
  <!-- CSS Just for demo purpose, don't include it in your project -->
  <link href="{{ asset('assets/demo/demo.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body class="">
  <div class="wrapper ">
    <div class="sidebar" data-color="orange">
      <!--
        Tip 1: You can change the color of the sidebar using: data-color="blue | green | orange | red | yellow"
    -->
      <div class="logo">
        <a href="http://www.creative-tim.com" class="simple-text logo-normal">
          | TestWeb |
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-wrapper" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        @include('inc.admin_navbar')
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-panel" id="main-panel">
      <!-- Navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent  bg-primary  navbar-absolute">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-wrapper">
            <div class="navbar-toggle">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar1"></span>
                <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar2"></span>
                <span class="navbar-toggler-bar bar3"></span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#pablo">Table List</a>
          </div>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation" aria-controls="navigation-index" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
            <span class="navbar-toggler-bar navbar-kebab"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navigation">
            <form>
              <div class="input-group no-border">
                <input type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                  <div class="input-group-text">
                    <i class="now-ui-icons ui-1_zoom-bold"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </form>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">


            <!-- Logout Button Starts -->
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                    {{ Auth::user()->name }}
                </a>

                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                    </a>

                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                        @csrf
                    </form>
                </div>
            </li>
            <!-- Logout Button Ends -->

            </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
      </nav>
      <!-- End Navbar -->
      <div class="panel-header panel-header-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="content">
        @yield('content')
      </div>
      <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <nav>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  TestWeb
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  About Us
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">
                  Blog
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
          <div class="copyright" id="copyright">
            <script>
              document.getElementById('copyright').appendChild(document.createTextNode(new Date().getFullYear()))
            </script>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--   Core JS Files   -->
  <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/core/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/core/popper.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/core/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/plugins/perfect-scrollbar.jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
  <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_KEY_HERE"></script>
  <!-- Chart JS -->
  <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/plugins/chartjs.min.js') }}"></script>
  <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
  <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/plugins/bootstrap-notify.js') }}"></script>
  <!-- Control Center for Now Ui Dashboard: parallax effects, scripts for the example pages etc -->
  <script src="{{ asset('assets/js/now-ui-dashboard.min.js?v=1.3.0') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!-- Now Ui Dashboard DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
  <script src="{{ asset('assets/demo/demo.js') }}"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: But what is the issue in the `master` file? Please share it with us. What you have corrected?

Comment: In users.blade.php I've added the sections but didn't add the '@extends('layouts.master')'. I kept on searching for error in routes and views but the errors was in users.blade.php

Answer (score 0):

Replace your route with below route code:

```
Route::get('users-list', function () {
      return view('admin/users');
  });
```

Blade file code:

```
<li>
   <!-- <a href="{{ url('/admin/users') }}">  -->
<a href="{{ url('users-list') }}">
      <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
      <p>Users Profiles</p>
    </a>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

just change your url in this way

Navbar

```
 <li>

<a href="{{ url('/admin/users-list') }}">
  <i class="now-ui-icons users_single-02"></i>
  <p>Users Profiles</p>
</a>
```

Comment: I've tried this method in the start, it was still giving me a blank page